# Spark Scala - How to construct Scala Map from nested JSON?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I've a nested json data with nested fields that I want to extract and construct a Scala Map.

Heres the sample JSON:

```
"nested_field": [
  {
    "airport": "sfo",
    "score": 1.0
  },
  {
    "airport": "phx",
    "score": 1.0
  },
  {
    "airport": "sjc",
    "score": 1.0
  }
]
```

I want to use [saveToES()](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-write-scala) and construct a Scala Map to index the field into ES index with mapping as below:

```
 "nested_field": {
    "properties": {
      "score": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "airport": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      }
    }
  }
```

The json file is read into the dataframe using spark.read.json("example.json"). Whats the right way to construct the Scala Map in this case?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you need to read it as scala json object and map it or transform it?

Comment: I want to know how to create a Map of Map objects in scala, thanks!

Comment: Please check the below answer if it matches what you need or not. You can also add another complex rules. if you need post another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the below sample code

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse



  case class AirPortScores(airport: String, score: Double)
  case class JsonRulesHandler(airports: List[AirPortScores])

  val jsonString: String = """{"airports":[{"airport":"sfo","score":1},{"airport":"phx","score":1},{"airport":"sjc","score":1}]}"""

  def loadJsonString(JsonString: String): JsonRulesHandler = {
  implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
  parse(JsonString).extract[JsonRulesHandler]
}

val parsedJson: JsonRulesHandler = loadJsonString(jsonString)
parsedJson.airports.foreach(println)//you can select parsedJson.airport or scores
//below ouput
AirPortScores(sfo,1.0)
AirPortScores(phx,1.0)
AirPortScores(sjc,1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks I think this will help!